# What's the meaning of plus sign before a Kotlin method?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm studiyng Kotlin and was watching the AndroidDevSummit, more specifically the presentation "Undestanding Compose" from Leland Richardson.

While the presentation (at 28min26sec), he shown the following code:

```
@Composable
fun App(items: List<String>, query: String) {
    val results = +memo(items, query) {
        items.filter { it.matches(query) }
    }
    // ...
}
```

What does the "+" plus sign before the "memo" method?

Comment: When an operator overload is used like this, you can Ctrl-click it in Intellij/Android Studio to jump to the function declaration to see what it does.

Comment: Ok, @Tenfour04, thank you, but it's just a feature and not the purpose of the "plus" sign, is it right?

Comment: Right. I’m just saying you can use that to find out what function the operator is calling.

Comment: Yes you can jump to declaration of the `unaryPlus`, but this doesn't mean that you can understand it's purpose. There you'll find just comment "Resolves the effect and returns the result."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `+` is kind of like an operator invoke for effects. The functions
>   that return effects just return an object for the effect and the `+`
>   says, "add it into the composition here"

by Adam Powell on [Kotlin Slack](http://slack.kotlinlang.org/)

[The full thread on kotlin slack](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1572032860437700?thread_ts=1572027829.429700&cid=CJLTWPH7S)

The `+` operator will be removed in the future, for states, probably will use Property Delegates, something like this: `var myState by state { "value" }`

Comment: Thank you @DevSrSouza, but could you clarify what it does and what is an Effect? The Slack's links is not open available.

Comment: From a talk that I listen days ago, Effects are anything that can changes in the real world, like a value that you can change in other place of your app and effect your UI.

try join by this link: http://slack.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: That Slack is only open to people with a jetbrains.com email address. This answer doesn't contain enough information on its own.