# What is the plus sign means in front of jetpack compose method name?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

what type of methods are those in android jetpack compose 
like this one bellow -

```
Text(text = text, style = +themeTextStyle { body1 })
```

Comment: That is the unary plus operator. Current editions of Compose use it a lot, though I am not certain exactly why it is used in this specific case. My understanding is that they will be dropping many, if not most, of these operators in future developer previews.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of plus sign before a Kotlin method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571670/whats-the-meaning-of-plus-sign-before-a-kotlin-method)

Comment: I wanted to know what it does and why they need it.

Comment: It is just there to resolve the reference to the style method and will like go away soon. docs https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/Effect#(androidx.compose.Effect).unaryPlus()